# Set server listening a sending messages from (servers/client) to (server/client) separately for each client

Tags: java, server, client, communication, bidirectional

Trying to write - distributive simulation framework, where program is represented by an array with moving objects, server send command to move, client answer objects out of array

Goal - server send text message to each connected client separately
     - client answer

Problem - can not find a way how to implement server listening and writing to one choosed client

Is there anyone, please, who can help me or get some idea?

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private ArrayList<BufferedReader> clientBufReaders;
private ArrayList<BufferedWriter> clientBufWriters;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
}

public Server() {
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(23456);
        this.clientBufReaders = new ArrayList<BufferedReader>();
        this.clientBufWriters = new ArrayList<BufferedWriter>();
        this.clients();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void clients() {

    Thread acceptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private Scanner in;

        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientBufReaders.add(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())));

                    clientBufWriters.add(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())));

                    this.in = new Scanner(System.in);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    );
    acceptThread.start();

    while (true) {
        synchronized (clientBufReaders) {
            for (BufferedReader in : clientBufReaders) {
                try {
                    if (in.ready()) {
                        System.out.println(in.readLine());
                    } else {
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```